# Incorrect oversized theme: 20.04 LTS, KDE, 2 monitors, nvidia 1050ti with proprietary driver,. The bug only happens if both are powered during boot

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, kde, themes, scaling

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS then installed KDE (kde-full) and now I have 2 monitors on a nvidia 1050 ti, 4k monitor and a 1440 monitor. The 4k monitor is in portrait and the 1440 is the primary in landscape. The 4k monitor is connected to a DVI-D on the card and the 1440 is connected to HDMI on the card.

Everything works but my primary 1440 has an oversized theme, greatly oversized. When I click the launcher/start menu it fills the entire vertical height. The task bar is huge, the windows title bars and decorations are huge along with their respective text. However, if I open Firefox all that is still huge but, the actual inner content/webpage is fine. So it appears the problem is just with the theme, or so I'm guessing.

If I boot without the 4K monitor having power, the 1440 is fine. If I plug in the 4k monitor after booting everything is fine. But, if I leave both powered on during boot, I wind up with this problem. I checked the scaling factor, both are 100% but, is it possible to set it lower to %50?.

Anyhow, I'm booting with the 4k monitor unplugged then plugging it after boot which has already become a little too painful. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem. It's just unusable. Anybody? I've tried setting QT_SCALE_FACTOR=0.75 in ~/.profile, but that really screwed things up. 

I'm sad. Every version of Kubuntu gets uglier and uglier. I had 18.X. My disk crapped out, so with a new one, I decided to go for 20.04. I had to bring up 16.04 on an old disk. Now that was nice, smooth. Dang.  Even the standard background on 20.04 makes me want to puke. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but I found that if I change the fonts, in System Settings >> Fonts and change all the fonts to something smaller, it rectifies itsself, after a few reboots. It seems to scale down all of the menu boxes, etc. I've changed mine to 10pt. My dual displays are 1920x1080.

FYI, I had the same problem with the high resolution laptop screen, which I don't use when the dual monitors are hooked up.

This approach is kind of counter-intuitive, since the fonts displayed are certainly not 10pts, but more like 14 or 16.

I somehow think this may be an issue with the display driver. Mine is Nividia 340, which apparently, Nivida no longer supports on newer kernels.